# object HTMLLlElement popup

Tags: javascript, html, object, browser, popup

I'm Roberto and I'm just a beginner of Javascript. I'm learning on a site and I'm going to get a book of Javascript very soon. 
I came across an example: I want to read the elements of the list and tweak the own class of each element( in this case, I want to delete the classes). 
As you all can see, for reading all the elements I wrote
  *var elementi = document.getElementsByTagName('li');* 
and to verify that everything is gone well I put an 
*alert(           elementi[0]   );*
 after the "var elementi..........", then i wrote the rest of the code. 
When I open the Window of the browser, It runs a pop-up that contains **object HTMLLlElement** text.
How can I get rid of this mistake? And what does it mean?

```js
var elementi = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
alert ( elementi[1] );
for ( var i = 0 ; i< elementi.lenght; i++){
  elementi[i].className = " ";

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css">

<title> Javascript </title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1><p>Javascript</p></h1>
  <p class="subtitle">Shopping list:<p>
    <ul id="lista">
      <li>Pasta</li>
      <li >Crocchette</li>
      <li >Lotamma</li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="corso01.js"></script>

</body>

</HTML>
```

Comment: What is the “mistake” and what do you want your program to do instead? `[object HTMLLIElement]` is just the string representation of your `<li>` DOM node.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to remove this line:

```
 alert ( elementi[1] );
```

To no longer get the message.  But, the message itself it just showing what type of object you have (element[1] is a list item HTML element). You could modify the alert to be more specific by changing it to:

```
 alert ( elementi[1].textContent);
```

Which would show "Crocchette" because that is the text that is stored in the list item.

It's coming up because the JavaScript code you've shown is automatically running as soon as the page is loaded.  In practice, you'll most likely want to move that code into a function that is called at a particular time, called an event. This could be when the user interacts with the page in some way (a click, a mouseover, etc.).

Also, you should change this:

```
 elementi[i].className = " "
```

to this:

```
 elementi[i].className = "";
```

The second one removes the space between the quotes so that instead of setting a class name to an actual space character, you are setting the class name to an empty string (no space).

Answer (score 0):

to remove a class from an element, you want to use the remove method on the classList property, like this:

```
elementi[i].classList.remove('lined');
```